# exclude a column from group by statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to exclude a column from **group by** statement, because it results in some redundant records. Are there any recommendations?

I use Oracle, and have a complex query which join 6 tables together, and want to use sql aggregate function (count), without duplicate result.

[image: field to be ecxclude]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

When using aggregate functions every column/column expression which is not an aggregate must be in the GROUP BY.

This is completely logical. If you're not aggregating the column then excluding it from the GROUP BY would force Oracle to chose a random value, which is not very useful.

If you don't want this column in your GROUP BY then *you* must decide what aggregation to apply to this column in order to return the appropriate data for your situation. You can't hand this responsibility off to the database engine.